# Saber si la posición de una lista está vacía

Tags: c#

Amigos buenos días tengo una `lista<>` vacía de 15 elementos de números enteros.

Digamos que inserto 3 datos en el posiciones 7 , 10, 11 y otros datos en otras posiciones de la `lista<>` generadas aleatoriamente. Todas las posiciones las genere aleatoriamente, por lo que pueden cambiar.

¿Cómo puedo saber si una posición esta vacía o tiene algún dato?

Comment: Podrías [edit] tu pregunta e incluir el código que avanzaste.

Answer (score 1):

En principio se me ocurre que las soluciones más simples a tu problema pueden ser dos:

1. Inicializar los elementos de la lista con un valor no válido. Por ejemplo si tu aplicación inserta valores mayores o iguales a 0, podrías inicializar los elementos con valor -1. De esta forma las posiciones con valor -1 equivaldrían a posiciones vacías.
2. La segunda posibilidad es crear una lista de elementos enteros "nulables"
   (`int?`). De esta forma cada posición podrá almacenar un valor entero o `null` en caso de estar vacío.

Answer (score 0):

Una lista (`List<int>`) o una matriz (`int[]`)?

En cualquier caso, la respuesta rápida es que no puedes saberlo. El valor por defecto de un `int` es `0` y no hay manera de saber si es `0` porque nadie dijo lo contrario o porque alguien decidió que debía ser `0`.

¿Solución? Crear una matriz secundaria de ayuda que te da precisamente esa información: `bool[]`. Cada elemento será verdadero si se ha variado la posicón de la lista correspondiente y falso si no.